# How to rename a button with double click

Tags: wpf, button, rename

I have a button with a custom template. Do you have any idea how I can rename the content in the button with a double click. 
This is what I have, but from code I cannot access b1.textBox to set the visibility to visible.

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse x:Name="outerCircle"  Fill="Red" Height="50" Width="50"/>
                        <Ellipse x:Name="innerCircle" Fill="White" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".9" ScaleY=".9"/>
                            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                        </Ellipse>
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

                        </Grid>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

---

```
 void button1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(e.Source.ToString());
        Button b1 = (Button)e.Source;
       // b1.textBox doesn't get displayed here.
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about

```
b1.Template.FindName("textBox",b1) as TextBox
```

?

Comment: yep, worked, i found it too, the only thing now is that I want for the textbox automatically to have the focus and when I click away on the canvas to loose the focus, and when the text is bigger than the box the text box grows only on the right, mooving the whole shape with itslef, i want only the text box to grow and not move the shape.

Comment: erm ... i don't really understand what you are trying to do ... is this still the same question?

Comment: no i'll ask a new one. i tried both 
    Keyboard.Focus(t1);
            FocusManager.SetIsFocusScope(t1, true);

to set the focus on the textbox but none of them work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add this to the style?
    `<EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="HandleDoubleClick" />`

Then in code behind:

```
protected void HandleDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)  
{  
  Button b1 = (Button)sender;
}
```

Comment: right, but if I try to do b1.textBox, I cannot access it in HandleDoubleClick